# Detail list not appearing when row tapped in previous list

Tags: list, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a list of languages, when a language is tapped in that list it should move to another list showing categories of that language. I'm using NavigationLink to navigate between menus.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct WordsView: View {

    @State private var selectAll = false
    @State private var language: Language?

    @Binding var selectedTab: Int

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: Language.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var languages: FetchedResults<Language>
    @FetchRequest(entity: SubCategory.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var subCategories: FetchedResults<SubCategory>
    @FetchRequest(entity: Thing.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var things: FetchedResults<Thing>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(languages, id: \.self) { language in
                        NavigationLink(destination: SubCategoryView(selectedTab: $selectedTab, language: language)){
                            LanguageRowView(language: language, selectAll: selectAll)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct SubCategoryView: View {
    
    @State private var subCategory: SubCategory?
    
    @Binding var selectedTab: Int

    @ObservedObject var homeworkColor = HomeworkTintColor()
        
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(entity: SubCategory.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var subCategories: FetchedResults<SubCategory>
    @FetchRequest(entity: Language.entity(), sortDescriptors: []) var languages: FetchedResults<Language>
    
    let language: Language
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            List {
                ForEach(language.subCategory?.allObjects as? [SubCategory] ?? [], id: \.self) { subCategory in
                    NavigationLink(destination: ThingView(language: language, subCategory: subCategory, selectedTab: $selectedTab)) {
                        SubCategoryRowView(subCategory: subCategory, selectAll: selectAll).        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I know the language parameter passed into SubCategoryView contains the language the user taps on, as I've been able to use it elsewhere in SubCategoryView.

In SubCategoryView, when I use the passed in value 'language' to access a database relationship 'subCategory' (which contains all the subcategories I want to display in a second list), the list does not appear at all.

[image]

Comment: Have you verified that your `language` does, in fact, contain `subCategories`? (Also, those `@FetchRequest`s don't appear to be used in the `SubCategoryView`.)

Comment: subCategory has a relationship with language, as can be seen in screenshot of my database.  I didn't include the code that requires @FetchRequest's, as I was using a minimal example that focused on the essential code.